# Zombicide Black Plague Spawning Question

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

If the setup requires you to have certain zombies in locked rooms from the start, when you open the door to that room do you still draw a card to add even more zombies to that room on top of what setup told you to put in it? (Example being the tutorial quest 0 where it has a fatty in a locked room alone, when you open the door to him do you spawn more?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, because the spawned zombies represent the unknown ones being revealed, e.g. the ones hiding under the bed!

> Opening a closed building for the first time reveals **all** the
>   Zombies inside **all** rooms of the building

Source: Page 20 of the rulebook. Emphasis is mine.